# Referencing an external class method in a Javascript file; getting ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, methods, reference

I have a class `Display` that uses values from a `helper.js` file for all its data and utilities. I am facing a problem where I need to call a method of the class from a function `helper.js`. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Display extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.imgHandler = this.imgHandler.bind(this);
      }

      imgHandler() {
        const displayValues = this.getValues();

        this.setState({
          displayValues
        });
      }
    }
```

helper.js

```
function renderIcon() {
  return (
    <img onClick={addHandler} />
  )
}
```

I tried creating an instance of `Display` in `helper.js` and setting the `onClick` handler in `renderIcon` as follows:

`const display = new Display();`
`<img onClick={display.imgHandler}>`

But doing this gave me an error:

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration display before initialization

Could I please get some help with accomplishing the above? Thanks!

Comment: Creating an instance of Display in helper.js creates a different Display object than the one used by React anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Where are you calling `renderIcon`?

Comment: @Bergi I am calling `renderIcon` in a child component of `Display`

Comment: @RandyCasburn The question you linked is asking for a function in a javascript file and not a class method. When I try this approach, I get a `unexpected token` error

Comment: With the little bit of info you've provided here, this appears to be a module import/export issue more so than anything else. Therefore, the dup is about getting that correct regardless of Class function or whatever.

Comment: @Jspake Can you show that code, please? Probably you should pass a [reference to an instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) from the `Display` component into your child component, and from there to `renderIcon` via a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the argument in the constructor `this`, the error suggests you are accessing `this` before it's ready to be used, which it would be fine to use anytime after `super` is called. Just rename it to `props` or something like that.

Make sure to update any `this` references in the constructor, except for the bind, it should be fine there

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made an error with in my sample code in the question. I am indeed using `props` in the constructor